# needing help understanding this array method call

Tags: java

I just learned recently arrays. This exercise calls to return an average. I am trying to figure out how to return an average from this method call.

```
public class Numbers {
   
   // calcAverage() takes in an int array and returns the average value of elements in the array as a double.
   public double calcAverage(int[] nums) {
     
  
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Numbers numObject = new Numbers();
      int [] nums = {1,2,3,4,5};
      System.out.println(numObject.calcAverage(nums)); 
   }
}
```

The following code resolved the issue:

package testingCode;

public class test {

```
public double calcAverage(int[] nums) {

    double sum;
    int i;
    
    
    sum = 0;
    
    for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) { 
        
        sum = sum + nums[i];
        
    }
    
    sum = sum / nums.length;
    
    
    
return sum;

   }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    test numObject = new test();
      int [] nums = {1,2,3,4,5};
      System.out.println(numObject.calcAverage(nums)); 
      
      
      

}
```

}

Comment: `return java.util.stream.IntStream.of(nums).average().orElseThrow();`.

Comment: So how would you express in words what you'd do to get an average of several numbers?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
// calcAverage() takes in an int array and returns the average value of elements in the array as a double.

public double calcAverage(int[] nums) {
    int sumOfElements=0;

    for (int num: nums){
        sumOfElements+=num;
    }
    return sumOfElements/(double)nums.length;
}
```

So the algorithm looks like:

1. Iterate over all elements in array to create the sum of them.
2. Divide the sum of the elements by the total number of elements. Attention! As both are integers it would be an integer division without decimal numbers. (That is why I cast the length to a double)

Comment: cannot find symbol|    symbol:   method length()

Comment: I always get confused about length. In Python its a function, in Java its an attribute.

Your solution return java.util.stream.IntStream.of(nums).average().orElseThrow(); works but it's too complicated for somebody learning Java.

Comment: I posted the code that resolved the issue. I didn't realize I needed to use a loop to add all elements but I am learning and I appreciate your patience.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you. Just some tips for your code:
- Try to write the first class name in capital letter: Test instead of test
- You can integrate the counter variable in the loop

for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) { 
        
        sum = sum + nums[i];
        
    }

3. You could further specify the variable sum. What does the sum variable represent? sumOfNums would be a great name in my opinion. Otherwise your code is a good step in the correct direction :D . Wish you a lot of fun with coding.